# Quantum Information Theory: How do I perform entanglement quantification calculations using the Quantum Heisenberg model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, ising-model, lattice-model

I have been reading *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* (10th edition) by Nielsen and Chuang and I am interested in calculating the level of entanglement (with entropy or some other measure I am not sure yet) between different 1-dimensional lattices containing $N$ particles that are either spin up or spin down (Quantum Heisenberg model). Suppose there are many identical lattices as well, and the spin is up sometimes and down other times.

I understand that a wave function for $N = 2$ particles looks something like this: $$| \psi \rangle = (\alpha_1 | up \rangle + \beta_1 | down \rangle) \otimes (\alpha_2 | up \rangle + \beta_2 | down \rangle)$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers.

How do I find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for each particle and how would you recommend I write some code to perform these calculations? How can the Schrodinger equation be solved? Are there any packages in any programming language?

Comment: How would you find arbitrary (up to normalization) coefficients? Find based on what? They can be whatever you want them to be. It's just a matter of preparation of your system. And what SE do you want to solve? The state stays the same unless you have an interaction Hamiltonian, which can be whatever you want it to be. The SE doesn't limit your imagination whatsoever. The entire line of questioning doesn't seem to make any sense to me. Unless you define the actual physics (do you mean Heisenberg spins with nearest neighbor interaction?), there is no here, here.

Comment: Your question might get a better response here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your second question. The way you wrote it down, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are, in principle, arbitrary constants (as long as $\vert \psi\rangle$ remains normalized). When talking about spin models, however, one is not interested in *arbitrary* states, but rather in either spectral properties (e.g. the ground state of the model, equilibrium or static observables, etc.), or nonequilibrium properties (time-evolution of observables, quenches, etc.).
So thats the first thing one needs to decide. Because, depending on what you are interested in, the numerical approach you want to use will be very different.

Either way, for both statics and dynamics you first need to create the Hamiltonian somehow. There are very efficient ways to do so but they may not be suited for a first read on this topic. Let me exemplify you the simplest, however a rather numerically expensive way, via brute-force.

Consider for example a single lattice (lets forget about multiple lattices for a moment, since they add another level of complexity which needs to be handled), the simplest quantum spin model would be the spin-1/2 quantum Ising model:

$$H=J\sum_{i}S_i^z S_{i+1}^z$$

which says that spins live on a 1D chain, and their only interaction is between nearest-neighbor spins via their $z$ spin components. Here, $S_i^z$ is really just a short-hand notation for the "Pauli-string" (neglecting fermionic spins for a moment, since one then has to include a Jordan-Wigner phase, again keeping it simple for the moment)

$$S_i^z = \mathbb{1}\otimes \dots \otimes \underbrace{S^z}_{\text{on position }i}\otimes \mathbb{1} \dots\otimes\mathbb{1}$$

where $\otimes$ is the tensor product and $S^z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ the $z$-Pauli matrix. Now you have to take the terms $S_i^z S_{i+1}^z$, which is a product of Pauli-strings

$$S_i^z S_{i+1}^z = (\mathbb{1}\otimes \dots \otimes \underbrace{S^z}_{\text{on position }i}\otimes \mathbb{1} \dots\otimes\mathbb{1} ) (\mathbb{1}\otimes \dots \otimes \underbrace{S^z}_{\text{on position }i+1}\otimes \mathbb{1} \dots\otimes\mathbb{1})$$

but there is a trick to evaluate expressions of these types, i.e.

$$S_i^z S_{i+1}^z = \mathbb{1}\cdot \mathbb{1}\otimes \dots \otimes \underbrace{S^z\cdot{\mathbb{1}}}_{\text{on position }i}\otimes \mathbb{1}\cdot S^z\otimes \dots\otimes\mathbb{1}\cdot \mathbb{1} $$

so the product can be performed for each single "lattice position" separately, without the need of performing a product of the (very large) Kronecker-contracted matrices. To get the Hamiltonian, one finally has to loop over all lattice sites and add up all of the terms $S_i^z S_{i+1}^z$ above.

I think it is really instructive to do this Pauli-string acrobatics once or twice on paper to get a good first idea about lattice Hamiltonians.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, the state you wrote can never be an entangled state. The generic form of an entangled state has to be
$a_1 |up>|up>+ a_2 |up>|down> + a_3 |down>|up> + a_4 |down>|down>$. Among the entangled states, $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} (|up>|up>+|down>|down>)$ and the like, are maximally entangled states.